# Error while asking for storage permissions via Permission Handler

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-permissions, file-manager

I keep getting the error: 
`D/permissions_handler( 6199): No permissions found in manifest for: []32 D/permissions_handler( 6199): No permissions found in manifest for: []9 D/permissions_handler( 6199): No permissions found in manifest for: []33 D/permissions_handler( 6199): No permissions found in manifest for: []22`

My code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:file_manager/file_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    requestStoragePermission();
  }

  Future<void> requestStorage() async {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.videos,
      Permission.photos,
      Permission.audio,
      Permission.manageExternalStorage,
    ].request();
    print(statuses[Permission.manageExternalStorage]);
    print(statuses[Permission.videos]);
    print(statuses[Permission.photos]);
    print(statuses[Permission.audio]); //Returns Permission.denied
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true, brightness: Brightness.dark),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

I am using Permission Handler v11.1.0 and File Manager v1.0.2. 
I have also added the required permission tags(Manage External Storage, and read Photos, Videos And Audios) in my AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: Wich permission is []15? Which is not found?

Comment: Its either READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE according to the[permission handler docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/permission_handler_platform_interface/latest/permission_handler_platform_interface/Permission/storage-constant.html)

Comment: Well find out which one. Ask them one by one. Not all at the same time.

Comment: Its used for both.

Comment: After reading the docs, I found that in Android 13, Permission.storage will always return Permission. denied. So I changed the code accordingly, however i still get the same error but for a different permission. I have also updated the code in the question

Comment: For which permission now?

Comment: for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_MEDIA_PHOTOS,READ_MEDIA_VIDEOS AND READ_MEDIA_AUDIOS

Comment: Why didnt you write that in your post? You should ask them one by one. Second time i tell. And you should treat MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE quite differently.

Comment: I just figured that out and have changed the code provided by me